# Getting 400 bad request while calling Licenspring webhook api

Tags: c#

I am using window form and calling Licensespring webhook api's method checklicense and getting 400 bad request. I wanted to check if a user is already created its trial license on the basis of hardware id, username and product name.Below you can find my code.

```
  private static async  void GetLicenseKeyByHardwareIdAndUser(string productCode)
         {
                    string sharedKey = "MVc12g949M7d1XiUM1F2gcJzNzKnXAaTgjrvEzh7AZc";
                    var apiKey = "ccdab2c7-0aa7-4c86-9d79-989f37980dce";

                    var hardwareId = "82A9-EA17-7F62-3BB9-F06A-659C-2280-8F9C-9470-BDC8-B2A2-9BEC-5B23-E89F-362D-1D99";

                    var product = "vp";

                    var username = "John@gmail.com";

                    var builder = new UriBuilder("https://api.licensespring.com/api/v4/check_license");
                    builder.Port = -1;
                    //generating url with query string having parameter hardware_id,username and product.
                    var query = HttpUtility.ParseQueryString(builder.Query);
                    query["hardware_id"] = hardwareId+"&";
                    query["username"] = username + "&";
                    query["product"] = product;

                    builder.Query = query.ToString();
                    string url = builder.ToString();

                    var date = DateTime.UtcNow.ToString();

                    //Preparing signed request header key
                    var authorization = string.Format("algorithm=hmac-sha256,headers=date," +
                        "signature={0},apikey={1}",CreateSHA256Signature(sharedKey), apiKey);

                    ServicePointManager.Expect100Continue = true;
                    ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Tls12;

                    var request = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Get, new Uri(url));

                         //Adding headers here 
                        request.Headers.Accept.Add(
                    new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));
                        request.Headers.TryAddWithoutValidation("Date", date);
                        request.Headers.TryAddWithoutValidation("Authorization", authorization);

                    //Send the request.
                   var response = await new HttpClient().SendAsync(request);
                    if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
                        {
                            var fileJsonString = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();

                            var result = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<dynamic>(fileJsonString).ToList();
                        }

            }


     public static string CreateSHA256Signature(string sharedKey)
        {
            var date = DateTime.UtcNow.ToString();
            var singningString = string.Format("licenseSpring\ndate: {0}", date);
            var hexHash = "";

            var encoding = new System.Text.ASCIIEncoding();
            byte[] keyByte = encoding.GetBytes(sharedKey);
            byte[] messageBytes = encoding.GetBytes(singningString);
            using (var hmacsha256 = new HMACSHA256(keyByte))
            {
                byte[] hashmessage = hmacsha256.ComputeHash(messageBytes);
                hexHash = Convert.ToBase64String(hashmessage);
            }
            return hexHash;
        }
```

So as you can see now there are two methods i have shared. One is "GetLicenseKeyByHardwareIdAndUser" which is calling webhook check_license api method, and the second one is calculating a signed `SH256 base64` string header needed in first method while sending aiuthorization header.
there is already a reference code written in Nodejs on there site [check License Method](https://docs.licensespring.com/docs/apiv4checklicense#apiv4checklicense)
Please help me here as i am stuck for quite a while. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I'm one of the founders of this service you are referencing.

First of all, I should say that you probably don't want to publish your API keys on a public forum like this. Please contact support and refer to this thread and we'll sort this out.

Secondly, if you're using C#, we wrote a [Licensing SDK for Winforms](https://docs.licensespring.com/docs/.net--c) which handles all of the encryption, signing and verifying the communication between the the server and the local machine, handles the device fingerprinting etc. I would suggest that unless you have very good reason to do so, you should most probably use the SDK instead of making calls directly to the LicenseAPI, as it will make your life orders of magnitude simpler.